# How can I use sumy.py on the command line?

Tags: python

After a successful installation of the sumy.py, I'm trying to use it from the command line as suggested in [sumy 0.3.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sumy):

```
$ sumy lex-rank --length=10 --url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_summarization # what's summarisation
```

but I'm getting an error:

```
'sumy' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

What should be an exact syntax of this command exactly?

Comment: The error makes it sound like it’s not the syntax at fault, the shell just can’t find anything called `sumy`. Is the `sumy` program in your $PATH?

Comment: @alexwlchan: Well, it is: PATH =%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\sumy .
Thanks for this suggestion though apparently that's not a solution.